# How can I read a .json file without jQuery in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

I am only asking the question because I've spent the last 2 days probably reading through countless other questions that are similar and tutorials and still can't get this to work.

I have a local .json file that I want to load up and parse with JavaScript. The file is called 'fakeData.json'. Its format is as such:

```
{"UIGroup": {"Parent": null, "Type": "public"}}
```

I'm using this to try to load the file:

```
<script src="fakeData.json"></script>
```

I am using this to try to parse the file:

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse('fakeData.json');
```

I am getting these errors:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : fakeData.json:1
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL : planetPage.html:11
```

May someone please help me, thanks.

Comment: Unless it's JSONP, referencing the file won't do much good, you need ajax.

Comment: How would I change my current JSON to a JSONP? I want to achieve this without the use of jquery, ajax, or anything else; basically as simple as it gets.

Comment: JSONP is a JavaScript program that consists of a function call (to a function that has to be defined elsewhere in the page) with one argument.

Comment: You can just change it to `var myJSON = {"UIGroup": {"Parent": null, "Type": "public"}}`, include the file before any scripts that use it, and reference it by the variable name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want it as simple as it gets, then I would prefix your json content  with

```
var jsonData = {"UIGroup": {"Parent": null, "Type": "public"}}....
```

which turns your file into a valid js file and then load it with

```
<script src="fakeData.json.js"></script>
```

after that, jsonData will have the required content because of literal object notation.

There is no way that you can load a json file into your page otherwise without ajax/httprequest.

Comment: Would I then be allowed to proceed to grab the values inside the fakeData.json.js file by say, by doing something such as: var obj = JSON.parse(jsonData); ?

Comment: The values are already assigned to jsonData, you could do `var obj = jsonData;` ;)

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the JSON text into a string variable before you can parse it.

This is generally achieved using [the XMLHttpRequest object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest).

`<script src="fakeData.json"></script>` will attempt to parse the JSON as JavaScript. This will either throw an error (as it does in your case) or create a data structure and then immediately discard it as it isn't assigned there.

Answer (score 1):

```
var jsonData;
function reqListener () {
  jsonData = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
  console.log(jsonData);
};

var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
oReq.onload = reqListener;
oReq.open("get", "fakeData.json", true);
oReq.send();
```

Comment: Assigning event handlers should be done *after* the call to `open` for maximum compatibility.

Comment: I get this error:
XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/Brian/Documents/visualizer/test.json. Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP. planetPage.html:19
(anonymous function)

Comment: Yes, you need to use HTTP for most file stuff in browsers.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep it all inline, with a JSON string, and access the object directly you could do something like this:

```
// copy all the JSON text from the file an keep store it in a local string variable. 
var jsonString = '{ "UIGroup": { "Parent": null, "Type": "public" }}';

// parse the string into a JavaScript object
var jsonObj = JSON.parse(jsonString);

// access the object as you usually would
alert(jsonObj.UIGroup.Type);
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MahzF/4/)